# Merge several arrays of objects into 1 in specific order

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's pretend I have 3 arrays:

```
arr1 = [
    {category: 'fruits', name: "apple"},
    {category: 'fruits', name: "banana"},
    {category: 'fruits', name: "orange"},
    {category: 'fruits', name: "ananas"}
]

arr2 = [
    {category: 'phones', name: "apple"},
    {category: 'phones', name: "saumsung"},
    {category: 'phones', name: "xioami"},
    {category: 'phones', name: "lg"},
    {category: 'phones', name: "huawei"},
]

arr3 = [
    {category: 'cars', name: "mercedes"},
    {category: 'cars', name: "bmw"},
    {category: 'cars', name: "toyota"}
]
```

As you can see they can have different lengths. And each of them can have up to 100 elements. What I want to get as a merge of all these arrays is something like this:

```
merged = [
   {category: 'fruits', name: "apple"},
   {category: 'fruits', name: "banana"},
   {category: 'fruits', name: "orange"},
   {category: 'phones', name: "apple"},
   {category: 'phones', name: "saumsung"},
   {category: 'phones', name: "xioami"},
   {category: 'cars', name: "mercedes"},
   {category: 'cars', name: "bmw"},
   {category: 'cars', name: "toyota"},
   {category: 'fruits', name: "ananas"},
   {category: 'phones', name: "lg"},
   {category: 'phones', name: "huawei"},
]
```

You can see that we are pushing to our merged array each time 3 items of each array (if it has three elements), and then we are doing that again until we take all elements from all 3 arrays.

I've tried this approach:

```
const lengthsArr = [arr1.length, arr2.length, arr3.length];
const max = Math.max(...lengthsArr);

let finalArr = [];
for(let i = 0; i < max; i = i+3) {
        finalArr.push(...getThree(arr1, i))
        finalArr.push(...getThree(arr2, i))
        finalArr.push(...getThree(arr3, i))
    }
}

function getThree(arr, index) {
    let result = [];
    for(let j = 0; j < index+3; j++) {
        if(arr[j]) {
            result.push(arr[j])
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

But it doesn't work as I expect.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Please add the code you've tried

Comment: I've added my approach

Comment: May I ask why you want to do something like this? It seams very impractical.

Comment: On the page there should presented in each row 3 different items (if there are 3 of specific category).

Comment: You want to get 3 elements or the length of the smallest array?

Comment: Those arrays can have up to 100 elements. And I need to take 3 from each array to present in one row and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `slice` like this:

```js
const arr1 = [{category:"fruits",name:"apple"},{category:"fruits",name:"banana"},{category:"fruits",name:"orange"},{category:"fruits",name:"ananas"}],
     arr2 = [{category:"phones",name:"apple"},{category:"phones",name:"saumsung"},{category:"phones",name:"xioami"},{category:"phones",name:"lg"},{category:"phones",name:"huawei"},],
     arr3 = [{category:"cars",name:"mercedes"},{category:"cars",name:"bmw"},{category:"cars",name:"toyota"}];

function merge(arrays) {
  const output = [];
  const max = Math.max(...arrays.map(arr => arr.length));
  
  for(let i = 0; i < max; i += 3) {
    arrays.forEach(arr => output.push(...arr.slice(i, i + 3)))
  }
  
  return output;
}

console.log(merge([arr1, arr2, arr3]))
```

Comment: It won't work for arrays if they have lengths - 10, 5, 7 for example.

Comment: I've almost done that)) Cool. I see my mistake. It works perfect.